# Programmatically update product.liquid on app install

Tags: shopify, shopify-app

Our Shopify app is activated by adding our snippet into the product and cart liquid files.

We noticed that adding the snippet is a tricky part for most merchants and we would like to offer them an option that we would do the heavy lifting for them.

My questions:

1. What is the best practice for doing such action?
2. How we can go on preview mode and wait till the merchant accept the change?
3. Any code samples using the Shopify Python SDK will be highly appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a pattern that will work, and cause the least damage on uninstall.

- download product.liquid using API (have fun ensuring you get the one that matters, as it could be in sections or snippets now)
- inject your special codes in that snippet
- upload your modified product.foobleflap.liquid

So now all your merchant need do is substitute your Liquid file for the original one. On App uninstall, no kittens have been killed, they need to simply revert back to their original Liquid file

Of course there are other patterns, but modding their original file with your snippet is probably least desirable from an uninstall perspective, as they would have to manually erase traces of your code.

Comment: thanks for the pattern, what it takes for merchants to replace liquid files? this adds a bit friction that we may want to avoid.

Is it possible to first show preview and then launch the theme change?
How do you recommend finding the right place to inject our snippet?

Comment: You are asking for too much help here. If you cannot figure out how to place your snippet in a file, you have deeper problems than anything StackOverflow is meant for. Try pattern matching in the Liquid to find something to trigger your insert... replacing a human is not easy, but you can do it... anyway, I gave you the right answer it seems, but you are now entering a rabbit hole that is deep and only you can explore it. All the best!

Comment: @DavidLazar Is there any way to automate this process without editing the .liquid file manually? I have an online store with Shopify, so each merchant needs to edit their product liquid file to make the same changes(personalization). There are some apps to customize the product page. I am looking for a way to automate.

Answer (score 0):

In 2024, all the smart kids just add a theme app extension to their App. All merchants can then just drag and drop your widget/snippet right into their theme and use it. Try that. It is 100% the way to go.